# iPhone MKMapView: set map region to show all pins on map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, html, region

I'm trying to set the map region (center and span) so that the map shows all pin-annotations at the same time.

I'm having trouble converting the long/lat coordinates from NSString to double, resp. make calculations with them. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)updateMemberPins{

//calculate new region to show on map
double center_long = 0.0f;
double center_lat = 0.0f;
double max_long = 0.0f;
double min_long = 0.0f;
double max_lat = 0.0f;
double min_lat = 0.0f;

for (Member *member in members) {
    
    //find min and max values
    if ([member.locLat doubleValue] > max_lat) {max_lat = [member.locLat doubleValue];}
    if ([member.locLat doubleValue] < min_lat) {min_lat = [member.locLat doubleValue];}
    if ([member.locLong doubleValue] > max_long) {max_long = [member.locLong doubleValue];}
    if ([member.locLong doubleValue] < min_long) {min_long = [member.locLong doubleValue];}
    
    //sum up long and lang to get average later
    center_lat = center_lat + [member.locLat doubleValue];
    center_long = center_long + [member.locLong doubleValue];
}

//calculate average long / lat
center_lat = center_lat / [members count];
center_long = center_long / [members count];

NSLog(@"center long: %d, center lat: %d", center_long, center_lat);
NSLog(@"max_long: %d, min_long: %d, max_lat: %d, min_lat: %d", max_long, min_long, max_lat, min_lat);
    
//create new region and set map
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: center_lat, longitude: center_long};
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(abs(max_lat) + abs(min_lat), abs(max_long) + abs(min_long));
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
[resultMapView setRegion:region];

//remove all pins from map
[resultMapView removeAnnotations:resultMapView.annotations];

//show member pins
for (id member in members) {
    [resultMapView addAnnotation:(Member *) member];
}
```

}

The result of the log-output is:

> center long: -1946827116, center lat: 1075651472
>
> max_long: -6267216, min_long: 1076018553, max_lat: 0, min_lat: 0

I think the problem comes from (wrongly) converting values from NSString to double, however I cannot find a way to make it work... The format of the location-strings is like '43.5686473'.

Any hints?

Comment: your start values for min max lat lon are wrong. Try these: double max_long = -360.0f; double min_long = 360.0f; double max_lat = -360.0f; double min_lat = 360.0f;

Comment: and span calculations? why add them? And also abs returns int not double so should be fabs: MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs(max_lat - min_lat), fabs(max_long - min_long));

Comment: thanks anyway, +1 it saved me some time

Comment: and also no need to accumulate lats lons in a loop. These can be calculated from min max values: center_lat = (min_lat + max_lat) / 2.0; center_long = (min_long + max_long) / 2.0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show double value in NSLog(), you should use `%f`, instead of `%d`
Change `NSLog()` part like this:

```
NSLog(@"center long: %f, center lat: %f", center_long, center_lat);
NSLog(@"max_long: %f, min_long: %f, max_lat: %f, min_lat: %f", max_long, min_long, max_lat, min_lat);
```

Also, using region from `MKMapView` is much simpler than making your own. Once it's set with zoom ratio, all you need is to dynamically move around the map with different coordinates.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
region.center = centerCoordinate;
region.span.longitudeDelta /= ratioZoomMax; // Bigger the value, closer the map view
region.span.latitudeDelta /= ratioZoomMax;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; // Choose if you want animate or not
```

Comment: Hey Peter! Thanks for your response. You are right with the NSLog statement. However, this guess this is not causing my miscalculations... The ratioZoom variant is nice, but I don't know this ratio. I have 'the outest coordiantes' that have to be visible on the map...

Comment: Well, it turned out that I was just confused with the bad numbers that the wrong Log-statement gave me. Then I had mad some mistakes in my calcs - and also bad data (0, 0 coordinates).

Comment: You can change `ratioZoomMax` to be smaller to show much wider area, showing pins that are far from one another. Reading your code again, I found that you had made unnecessary addition to find center value. As you've already figured out, to find the center, you just have to do `(lowestValue + highestValue)/2.0`, not dividing it by `[members count]`

Comment: Correct! This makes it even simpler ;-) I'll post my final code that is now working as it should. Thank you Peter!

Comment: You are welcome~ I simply shared what I learned. Glad it was helpful

Answer (score 22):

The final, working code for those looking for something similiar:

```
    - (void)updateMemberPins{

    //remove all pins from map
    [resultMapView removeAnnotations:resultMapView.annotations];

    if ([members count] > 0) {

        @try {
            //calculate new region to show on map           
            Member *firstMember = [members objectAtIndex:0];
            double max_long = [firstMember.locLong doubleValue];
            double min_long = [firstMember.locLong doubleValue];
            double max_lat = [firstMember.locLat doubleValue];
            double min_lat = [firstMember.locLat doubleValue];

            //find min and max values
            for (Member *member in members) {
                if ([member.locLat doubleValue] > max_lat) {max_lat = [member.locLat doubleValue];}
                if ([member.locLat doubleValue] < min_lat) {min_lat = [member.locLat doubleValue];}
                if ([member.locLong doubleValue] > max_long) {max_long = [member.locLong doubleValue];}
                if ([member.locLong doubleValue] < min_long) {min_long = [member.locLong doubleValue];}
            }

            //calculate center of map
            double center_long = (max_long + min_long) / 2;
            double center_lat = (max_lat + min_lat) / 2;

            //calculate deltas
            double deltaLat = abs(max_lat - min_lat);
            double deltaLong = abs(max_long - min_long);

            //set minimal delta
            if (deltaLat < 5) {deltaLat = 5;}
            if (deltaLong < 5) {deltaLong = 5;}

            //debug
            //NSLog(@"center long: %f, center lat: %f", center_long, center_lat);
            //NSLog(@"max_long: %f, min_long: %f, max_lat: %f, min_lat: %f", max_long, min_long, max_lat, min_lat);

            //create new region and set map
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: center_lat, longitude: center_long};
            MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(deltaLat, deltaLong);
            MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
            [resultMapView setRegion:region];


        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Error calculating new map region: %@", e);
        }
        @finally {
            //show member pins
            for (id member in members) {
                [resultMapView addAnnotation:(Member *) member];
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Might be better off using fabs(), rather than abs(). abs() gave me some problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
//show member pins
        for (id member in members) {
            [resultMapView addAnnotation:(Member *) member];
        }
```

This can be replaced with

```
[resultMapView addAnnotations:members];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this peace of code:

```
-(void)updateMemberPins
{
    if([members count] == 0)
        return;

    double minLat = 90;
    double minLon = 180;
    double maxLat = -90;
    double maxLon = -180;

    for(Member *member in members)
    {
        minLat = fmin(minLat, [member.locLat doubleValue]);
        minLon = fmin(minLon, [member.locLong doubleValue]);
        maxLat = fmax(maxLat, [member.locLat doubleValue]);
        maxLon = fmax(maxLon, [member.locLong doubleValue]);
    }

    NSLog(@"MAX LAT: %f, MIN LAT: %f, MAX LONG: %f, MIN LONG: %f,", maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon);

    double midLat =  (minLat + maxLat)/2;
    double midLong = (minLon + maxLon)/2;

    double deltaLat = abs(maxLat - minLat);
    double deltaLong = abs(maxLon - minLon);

    if (deltaLat < 5) {deltaLat = 5;}
    if (deltaLong < 5) {deltaLong = 5;}

    //...
}
```